# Why am I still getting `insert or update on table "table Name" violates foreign key constraint` error?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, nestjs, knex.js

I'm getting this error:

`insert or update on table "table Name" violates foreign key constraint`

I know it means the foreign key (`id`) does not exist in the foreign table. But the key is there.

My knex script:

```
import { Knex } from "knex";

export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
  await knex.schema.createTable("notification", (table) => {
    table.uuid("id").notNullable().unique().primary().defaultTo(knex.raw("uuid_generate_v4()"));
    table.string("user_id").notNullable().index().references("id").inTable("user");
    table.string("type").notNullable();
    table.string("location").notNullable();
    table.string("asset").nullable();
    table.string("reliability").nullable();
    table.string("related_due_type").nullable();
    table.string("related_entity_id").nullable();
    table.timestamps(true, true);
  });
}

export async function down(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
  await knex.schema.dropTableIfExists("notification");
}
```

The error I get when I run:

> `original: error: insert or update on table "notification" violates foreign key constraint "notification_user_id_foreign"`
>
> `detail: 'Key (user_id)=(y3er67cv-939a-e45t-b1ad-30566e3b48aa) is not present in table "user".'`

But I checked the database, and that `id` exists.

Example:

```
it("should create a User Notification", async () => {
    const expectedDto: CreateUserNotificationDto = {
      channel: NotificationChannel.email,
      type: RelatedEntityType.integrationFetchRequest,
      location: new Date(new Date().getDate()).toString(),
      assest: new Date(new Date().getDate()).toString(),
      related_due_type: "integrationRequest1",
      relatedEntityType: RelatedEntityType.integrationFetchRequest,
      user_id='y3er67cv-939a-e45t-b1ad-30566e3b48aa'
    };

const response = await request(httpServer).post(`/Notification`).send(expectedDto);
    expect(response.status).toBe(201);
    expect(response.body).toEqual(expect.objectContaining(expectedDto));
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: can you show examples?

Comment: 1) I would take the error as correct. So that leads to a) You are pointing at different database or different schema.table when running the various code examples. b) The test is running on the `notification` table before the `user` table is populated with data. FYI, `user` is not a good name as it is a reserved word per here [Key words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).